# Programmatic NSLayoutConstraint not working expectedly in UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a chat application with variable row height. Here's what I put in the UIViewController class's viewDidLoad() holding the UITableView for the purpose:

```
tblMessages.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
tblMessages.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Next I've created a custom UITableViewCell class with following codes:

```
    class MessageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var messageBG = UIView()
    var textMessage = UILabel()

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        messageBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        messageBG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 40)
        messageBG.layer.cornerRadius = 20

        self.textMessage.numberOfLines = 0
        self.textMessage.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

        addSubview(messageBG)
        addSubview(textMessage)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        refreshView()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func refreshView()
    {
        //NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraints())

        textMessage.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textMessage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textMessage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textMessage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -50))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textMessage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textMessage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 19))

        self.messageBG.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.messageBG, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.messageBG, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.messageBG, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -49))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.messageBG, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 6))
        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.messageBG, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 6))
    }
}
```

In above, I'm adding a coloured background (UIView) and a multi-line UILabel. When passing a long text to a row cell, I got this when application starts: http://postimg.org/image/8xvcshkfh/

When I rotate the view in simulator, then I have this but yet with wrong dimension/constraints: http://postimg.org/image/oyl1yyi3h/

Can somebody help me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found lately that I made one mistake in my code -

```
self.addConstraint(..)
```

Should replace with:

```
self.contentView.addConstraint(..)
```